# git pull --rebase but do not try to merge some files

Tags: git

I have a local branch with a file **"foobar"** which I don't want to be merged
with **origin/master** when I `git pull --rebase` the branch with **origin/master**.

I currently do:

```
 cp foobar /tmp
 git pull --rebase
 cp /tmp/foobar .
 git add foobar
 git rebase --continue
```

Is there any way to avoid all this and just ignore said file during a `pull --rebase`?

NB/For those asking what I'm doing: Local branch **foobar** is a complete rewrite of **origin/master**'s **foobar** and I would like it not to be merged with **master** until my local feature is completely finished.

Comment: What about `.gitignore`?

Comment: I’m not sure what you are trying to do there. If there are conflicts in `/tmp/foobar` then just adding that (*after conflict markers were added*) is a very bad idea. And `git rebase continue` is not a valid usage either.

Comment: @poke I've added an explanation on why I want foobar ignored. Adding foobar after conflict markers allow the rebase to continue, as if I had manually fixed it (which I actually did, by removing all changes from master) Why would this be a bad idea? Also fixed "continue" to "--continue"

Comment: It's a bad idea, since if you are completely rewriting the code, and someone else adds features on the master branch, then you won't even notice... and your rewritten code won't work like the one on the master branch.

Comment: Very valid point, but in this case I'm maintaining the file in both branches (master + local), so every time I add a feature in the old interface, I also add it in the new interface style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to do a `git pull rebase` but prefer current branch version if a conflict arises:

```
git pull --rebase -X ours
```

The `-X` stands for "strategy" and is documented in `man git-rebase`.

Answer (score 3):

Add the file to the `.gitignore` so it will be undetectable by git.

If you still want the file in the repository (with default values for example) you should use the `assume-unchanged` flag on the tracked file.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]

Comment: when i changed the file (assume-unchanged) then exec rebase.
Git still show "needs commit local changed". How can i rebase?